# UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct {ContractName.StructName} memory[] memory to storage not yet supported

Tags: storage, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, decentralized-applications

・I want to create the lottery contract that user can buy some lottery numbers.
And, if the lottery was finished, I want to initialize it to create a new lottery.
That's why we implemented it this way.

`lotChances = new LotChance[](0);`

But, I faced this is error ...

> UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Lottery.LotChance memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.

Minimal example:

```
contract Lottery {
  // Lot Structs
  struct LotChance {
    address payable userAddress;
    uint256 ids;
  }
  LotChance[] public lotChances;

  function getResult() public onlyOwner {
 
    luckyPerson.transfer(address(this).balance);
    lotteryId++;
    lotChances = new LotChance[](0);
  }
}
```

Please advise me

Answer (score 0):

For reset an array and set his values to default you can use `delete` keyword in Solidity. In your case, you must to change your `getResult()` function in this way:

```
function getResult() public onlyOwner {
    luckyPerson.transfer(address(this).balance);
    lotteryId++;
    delete lotChances;
}
```

You can see an example of smart contract code, here following:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity 0.8.7;
    
contract Lottery {
    address owner;
    
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    // Lot Structs
    struct LotChance {
        address payable userAddress;
        uint256 ids;
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You aren't smart contract owner!");
        _;
    }
    
    LotChance[] public lotChances;
    
    function getResult(address _luckyPerson) public onlyOwner {
        uint lotteryId = 0;
        payable(_luckyPerson).transfer(address(this).balance);
        lotteryId++;
        // I reset array length about to '0'
        delete lotChances;
    }
    
    function partecipateToLottery(uint _id) public {
        lotChances.push(LotChance(payable(msg.sender), _id));
    }
    
    function getLengthArray() external view returns(uint) {
        return lotChances.length;
    } 
}
```